# Where can I find the source files of eclipse icons?

Tags: eclipse, icons

I want to use some of the icons in eclipse (package, java project, etc.) in an illustrator graphic. To get best results, I'd like to have the icons in vector format or at least an editable format. Is there any source I can get them from? I found the jar `org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.5.2.r352_v20100106-0800.jar`, where all the icons are included, but unfortunately as gif files.
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eclipse has a [User Interface Guidelines](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines) wiki page, where it is described how to create your own icons. Also, it includes several templates of the common elements, which you can use for base of your own icons:

- [Common elements](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/a8/Common_icon_elements.zip)
- [Core wizards elements](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/ac/Core_wizard_concepts.zip)
- [Core icons elements](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/0/0f/Core_icon_concepts.zip)
- etc.

There is a chance that the icon you want is not available, but it is worth a try.

Comment: It's a beginning, thank you :-) I'll wait whether some knows where to find them in an editable form, but if there are no answers tomorrow I'll accept your answer

Comment: Where can we get licensing information for these icons?

Answer (score 4):

There is a GIT repository at Eclipse with SVG sources for many of the icons: https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.images.git/

It doesn't have all of them, since the SVG version of the icons started as an individual project, and then it was adopted by Eclipse. However it's a great source to create your own icons that follows the Eclipse style.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the **Plug-in Image Browser**:

> Window > Show View > Other... > Plug-in Development > Plug-in Image
>   Browser

You can browse all the images available in your Eclipse; select one to have further information and then press the "Save" icon to save it somewhere.

See also https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fviews%2Fimage_browser_view.htm

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that the icons are available as a vector form, as they were crafted to look good on that small (16x16px) resolution. That cannot be reached by simply downsizing a vector graphic.