# Where can Eclipse icons be downloaded

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an eclipse ECP application where I wanted to use the Eclipse icons like project, folder, task, etc.

Can anyone help me from where I can download these icons? I searched in `workspace/.metadata/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundlepool` but I could not find the Eclipse related icons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the source files of eclipse icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764855/where-can-i-find-the-source-files-of-eclipse-icons)

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.images

Comment: Why does some one want this open ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to add to [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137007/2986905):

- If you search the `.bundlepool` directory for icons you will have to look into/extract each jar. The icons are usually stored under an `icons` folder in the jar.
- a collection of commonly used Eclipse icons can be found here: http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/
- since Eclipse Kepler, PDE has a [Plug-in Image Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fviews%2Fimage_browser_view.htm) to browse images inside plug-ins from the workspace or target platform.

Answer (score 2):

In your plugin.xml you can use it like this

```
<command
           commandId="id"
           icon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.ide/icons/full/obj16/hprio_tsk.gif"
           style="push"
           tooltip="%cmd1.commandtooltip">                  
</command>
```

You can use Plugin image browser to find it reference. Check [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fviews%2Fimage_browser_view.htm).

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020 http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/ is offline unfortunately.

I found https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-icons.htm to contain some useful Eclipse icons.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the standard Eclipse icons can be accessed from the shared images registry using something like:

```java
ISharedImage sharedImages = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages();

Image image = sharedImages.getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FOLDER);

ImageDescriptor imageDesc = sharedImages.getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FILE);
```

The `org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages` interface contains the names of the available images.

Note: This is not available in e4 RCPs.

The icon files themselves are stored in the various plugin jar files, you can use a tool like the standard `jar` tool to extract them.

Comment: But does it contain almost all the icons? I wanted to use some icons like  task icons. I have used the icons from the workspace few years ago. it contains almost all icons.

Comment: The shared images contain the most common. All the icons are in the various plugin jars.